# Node.js not working on windows (file error)

Tags: node.js

I had installed node.js and when I try to exceute simple `Hello world` it opens that file, instead of showing me the hello world and also it opens the same file every time, whether I try to execute the different .js files. I'm new to node.js, kindly help...thanks in advance!

Comment: i have re installed,cleared the cache, added the enviromnment varibales but every time i run node hello.js in cmd, it opens the hello.js file, not showing the output

Answer (score 0):

Download the Windows executable here: http://nodejs.org/#download

Copy the file to C:\

Create C:\hello.js

Paste in the following content:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Save the file

Start -> Run... -> cmd

c:

C:>node hello.js

```
Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/
```

Comment: i have re installed,cleared the cache, added the enviromnment varibales but  every time i  run node hello.js in cmd, it opens the hello.js file, not showing the output

Comment: to make sure that the node is installed correctly please do the following 
1- open the command line 
2-  `> node --version`
if it gave you results like `v0.12.0` so it's correctly installed or you have to re install it 
* if it correctly installed please paste your code of `hello.js`

Comment: node -v v0.12.2

npm -v 2.7.4

hello.js
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');